# django admin site - display model objects created by request.user only

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have simple blog app which have `author=models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)` field. Blog posts are created from django admin site, and I use [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) to get author which is request.user.

Now I want that user (is_staff) can see only his own posts, when he browse model posts. But by default all blog posts are displayed, so how can I hide blog posts created by other users? Of course superusers need to see all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override the `get_queryset` method on the ModelAdmin subclass. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) has an example of exactly what you're asking for: displaying only objects related to the current user.

Comment: What if the related user is defined in the model (no FK to user), is there a way to achieve the same maybe using Log entries or something?

Comment: The link in the answer has rotted. Here is the updated link to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) for Django 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is lazy. Here's a sample code I use.
So first you create a QuerySet Manager, I usually have mine in models.py, which does something like this (in this case I'm calling the model Blog):

```
class BlogManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        query = Blog.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            query = UserProfile.objects.all()
        return query
```

Make sure your admin.py then has this:

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = BlogManager.get_queryset(self, request)
        return queryset
```

So it might look like:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   #add any other code here

   #Using that queryset manager created before
   def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = BlogManager.get_queryset(self, request)
        return queryset
admin.site.register(BlogAdmin)
```

Hope this helps anyone!